# Netbeans does not package class library jar to ear file when deploying Enterprise Application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, netbeans-7

I build a java enteprise application in netbeans 7.1 which consists of two EJB modules. One of the EJB modules has a reference to another class library project, lets call it MyUtilities. When i deploy the application, its ear file does not contain MyUtilities.jar file. When i add to the other EJB module libraries MyUtilites project, although its not necessary, the ear file is built correctly and under its lib folder, MyUtilities.jar exists. 
Anyone with the same issue?

Thanks

Comment: I also noticed that if i go to Project properties --> Libraries, whatever jar i add there does not have any effect on generated ear file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the setting of the checkbox "Package required JARs in EJB jar" in the Build | Packaing dialog?

This is a new option which I found after upgrading a NetBeans 6.5.1 EJBModule project which had also no longer the references JARs bundled in the EJB jar.

Comment: No i didnt check this setting. In netbeans 7.2 the problem doesnt seem to appear. Thanks anyway